# How to calculate the existing Household Number?

Tags: xstring

I am going to maintain the database of my church which i got stuck on calculation of existing household number of a particular area service however i am able to calculate the existing members of areawise, If a household is transfer from my church then how to update the household to get the existing household of each Area in latex, here is the MWE, here Unique ID is the household number
, I want the "Existing Household" column entry as you can see in the first image there is a entry for "Existing Members" column questions is very simple but hard to implement for me to fill the Existing Household of each Areawise column, the first image shown above is the  data of my church of my church members which is going to read from .csv file as you can see the Unique ID entry is ID for each household in this data i have overall total number of house is 6 as you can see the "Transfer" column, N=No transfer and Y=Yes transfer,  if a household left my church then remaining total existing household is 5, lets look  at the first image household ID of DBC0006 and DBC0004 has taken the transfer from my church and in this household ID of DBC0006 we have total members of 5 which are Mr. Raju, Mr. Virendra Teron, Mr. Klen, Miss Beauty  and Mr. Elvin (i.e they belong to same household ID of DBC0006 ) and this household is belong from column Areawise of "Area No. 2" similarly for DBC0004 having total members of 2 which are Mr. Gilbert and Mr. Dinesh ,so my table should give the updated column entry and updated existing members as shown in the 3rd image

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{report}
 \usepackage[top=0.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
 \usepackage{setspace,filecontents}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,xstring,datatool,xintexpr,longtable,minted} %for including eps graphics

 \renewcommand{\dtldisplaystarttab}{\toprule}
 \renewcommand{\dtldisplayafterhead}{\midrule}
 \renewcommand{\dtldisplayendtab}{\\\bottomrule}

 \begin{filecontents*}{MemberSummary.csv}
 Unique ID,Name,Gender,Baptised,Death,Transfer,Areawise
 DBC0001,Mr. John,M,Y,N,N,Area No.1
 DBC0002,Miss Elizabeth,F,Y,N,N,Area No.1
 DBC0003,Mr. Thomas,M,N,N,N,Area No.2
 ,Miss Maya,F,N,Y,,Area No.2
 DBC0004,Mr. Gilbert,M,Y,N,Y,Area No.3
 ,Mr. Dinesh,M,N,Y,,Area No.3
 DBC0005,Miss Shanti,F,N,N,N,Area No.1
 ,Mr. Rajesh,M,Y,N,N,Area No.1
 DBC0006,Mr. Raju,M,Y,N,Y,Area No.2
 ,Mr. Virendra Teron,M,Y,Y,,Area No.2
 ,Mr. Klen,M,Y,N,Y,Area No.2
 ,Miss Beauty,F,Y,Y,,Area No.2
 ,Mr. Elvin,M,Y,Y,,Area No.2
 \end{filecontents*}


 \renewcommand{\dtldisplaystarttab}{\toprule}
 \renewcommand{\dtldisplayafterhead}{\midrule}
 \renewcommand{\dtldisplayendtab}{\\\bottomrule}


 \DTLloaddb{summary}{MemberSummary.csv}

 \newcounter{A}
 \newcounter{B}
 \newcounter{C}
 \newcounter{TotalA}
 \newcounter{AH1}
 \newcounter{AH2}
 \newcounter{AH3}
 \newcounter{TotalAH}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{longtable}{llccccl}
 \toprule
 Unique ID & Name & Gender & Baptised & Death & Transfer & Areawise\\
 \midrule
 \DTLforeach*{summary}{\id=Unique ID,\name=Name,\g=Gender,\b=Baptised,\d=Death,\tr=Transfer,\a=Areawise}{

 \IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area No.1}{\stepcounter{A}}{}}{}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area No.2}{\stepcounter{B}}{}}{}}{}
 \IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area No.3}{\stepcounter{C}}{}}{}}{}

 \id & \name & \g & \b & \d & \tr & \a \\

 }
 \\\bottomrule
 \end{longtable}

 \setcounter{TotalA}{\numexpr\value{A}+\value{B}+\value{C}}

 \bigskip

 \begin{tabular}{lcc}
 \toprule
 Areawise &Existing Household & Existing Members\\
 \midrule
 Area No.1 & &\theA \\
 Area No.2 & &\theB \\
 Area No.3 & &\theC \\
 \bottomrule
 Total & &\theTotalA

 \end{tabular}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

updated existing table entry

[image]

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. What calculation for you want to perform, that is what output do you want for the provided input?

Comment: The output is shown now in 3rd image please have a look@David Carlisle

Comment: Your example is not very minimal. You don't need to make people compile with shell escape, which I'm reluctant to do with other people's code unless I'm *very* certain of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{MemberSummary.csv}
Unique ID,Name,Gender,Baptised,Death,Transfer,Areawise
DBC0001,Mr. John,M,Y,N,N,Area No.1
DBC0002,Miss Elizabeth,F,Y,N,N,Area No.1
DBC0003,Mr. Thomas,M,N,N,N,Area No.2
,Miss Maya,F,N,Y,,Area No.2
DBC0004,Mr. Gilbert,M,Y,N,Y,Area No.3
,Mr. Dinesh,M,N,Y,,Area No.3
DBC0005,Miss Shanti,F,N,N,N,Area No.1
,Mr. Rajesh,M,Y,N,N,Area No.1
DBC0006,Mr. Raju,M,Y,N,Y,Area No.2
,Mr. Virendra Teron,M,Y,Y,,Area No.2
,Mr. Klen,M,Y,N,Y,Area No.2
,Miss Beauty,F,Y,Y,,Area No.2
,Mr. Elvin,M,Y,Y,,Area No.2
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs,xstring,datatool,longtable}

\renewcommand{\dtldisplaystarttab}{\toprule}
\renewcommand{\dtldisplayafterhead}{\midrule}
\renewcommand{\dtldisplayendtab}{\\\bottomrule}

\renewcommand{\dtldisplaystarttab}{\toprule}
\renewcommand{\dtldisplayafterhead}{\midrule}
\renewcommand{\dtldisplayendtab}{\\\bottomrule}


\DTLloaddb{summary}{MemberSummary.csv}

\newcounter{A}
\newcounter{B}
\newcounter{C}
\newcounter{TotalA}
\newcounter{AH}
\newcounter{BH}
\newcounter{CH}
\newcounter{TotalAH}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{llccccl}
  \toprule
  Unique ID & Name & Gender & Baptised & Death & Transfer & Areawise\\
  \midrule
  \DTLforeach*{summary}{\id=Unique ID,\name=Name,\g=Gender,\b=Baptised,\d=Death,\tr=Transfer,\a=Areawise}{

    \IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area No.1}{\stepcounter{A}}{}}{}}{}
    \IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area No.2}{\stepcounter{B}}{}}{}}{}
    \IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area No.3}{\stepcounter{C}}{}}{}}{}
    \IfStrEq{\id}{}{}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area No.1}{\stepcounter{AH}}{}}{}}{}}
    \IfStrEq{\id}{}{}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area No.2}{\stepcounter{BH}}{}}{}}{}}
    \IfStrEq{\id}{}{}{\IfStrEq{\d}{N}{\IfStrEq{\tr}{N}{\IfStrEq{\a}{Area No.3}{\stepcounter{CH}}{}}{}}{}}

    \id & \name & \g & \b & \d & \tr & \a \\

  }
  \\\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\setcounter{TotalA}{\numexpr\value{A}+\value{B}+\value{C}}
\setcounter{TotalAH}{\numexpr\value{AH}+\value{BH}+\value{CH}}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lcc}
  \toprule
  Areawise &Existing Household & Existing Members\\
  \midrule
  Area No.1 & \theAH &\theA \\
  Area No.2 & \theBH &\theB \\
  Area No.3 & \theCH &\theC \\
  \midrule
  Total & \theTotalAH &\theTotalA\\
  \bottomrule

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]